# amchart - Only showing every second value in X axis

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'e been struggling with this for a while now, and tried all sorts of different configurations, however no matter what I try I'm unable to get the values and grid lines to show for every column in my chart.

```
Here's an image of what I'm aiming for
```

[image: end goal]

You can see from the design that every column has a light grey bar behind it that is 100% tall. (I'm a bit stuck on the best way to achieve this too, as currently I'm showing a grid with a thick line, but if someone zooms the grid line stays thing while the columns grow fat.)

```
Here's where I'm at so far
```

[image]

I've got a fiddle of my progress here: http://jsfiddle.net/duellsy/wv1sasyb/

Would appreciate any help on

1. Showing the light grey bar behind every column
2. Making sure light grey bar stays same width if user zooms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set equalSpacing to false (default). I am not yet sure why with this setting not all labels are visible - need to investigate. As for grey columns - you can add another graph to your chart and set clustered and stacked to false: http://jsfiddle.net/wv1sasyb/2/

```
 {
        "columnWidth": 0.43,
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "fillColors": "#DADADA",
        "id": "AmGraph-3",
        "lineThickness": 0,
        "title": "Contextual",
        "type": "column",
        "clustered":false,
        "stacked":false,
        "valueField": "column-3",
        "showHandOnHover": true,
    }
```

Comment: ended up adding another graph to the chart before I saw your response, but since it's the same thing... ticks for you